# Symfony2 and Jquery mobile integration

Tags: jquery-mobile, symfony

Is it possible to integrate Jquery mobile and symfony2 to create a web mobile application ?

Comment: can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Did you perform a [search on Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Jquery%20mobile%20and%20symfony2) first ?

- Here a [great Spannish presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/pgodel/creacion-de-aplicaciones-moviles-con-symfony2) about Symfony 2 and jQuery Mobile
- Here is a [category](http://www.danielecentamore.com/wordpress/?cat=4) (the last post to the top, so go to the bottom to see the story) from a guy who built a king of game with Symfony 2 and jQuery mobile
- Here is a [french post about Symfony 2 and jQuery mobile](http://blog.fruitsoftware.com/2011/01/jquery-mobile-doctrine-2-et-autres-tests/) (from the PR4)